# Can we define a single immutant state of a device (modern computers at least) to derive a key from?

Tags: encryption, key

Please be open and bear with me, I read a lot about encryption, but practiced very little.

I want to write a simple application that uses common encryption algorithms, but based on a derived key without the users choice. I know this has many drawbacks, but this is for experiment. I will point what is the most clear drawback later on.

For this, the only practical option that appears to me, is to derive the key with a deterministic function from im-mutant information (hardware state including ROM), like bios serial number for example; But also from other information if possible and with other hidden choices, to add some kind of salt, that is hard to reproduce.

Why is this ? Because it would be practical for easier encryption, if it happens that data use is only relevant to that particular state. If state changes, encrypted state is lost.

Soft state neighboring the -to be encrypted data- is also an option. For example:
data to be encrypted is a piece of Python code to hide, if this code is to be executed only when Python compiler is there, Pip is there, Pandas is there, then their targeted versions would compose the soft state of the key. If anything changes to a newer version, data would be lost forever.

Another practical option, would be paid games, the game only runs on one personal computer, it can't be decrypted elsewhere.

At the other hand, the main drawback, probably the first aim of encryption is to hide communicated date through network. This is not our case.

If this is possible, what are possible flaws ?

Comment: A TPM's PCRs contain a hash which is fed firmware and firmware configuration.

Comment: very neat, I will definitely read about, and how to interface with them.

Comment: From what you're describing, this doesn't look like encryption at all. What are you building? A machine fingerprint? DRM? What makes an encryption is the key must be unknown to anyone else but the user or the system. Hardware serials are usually not secret, the manufacture of the computer might have recorded the serials of the components used in the machine.

Comment: if the state changes, data can no longer be read. lost somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question that you have to ask yourself is, why do you want to use encryption? In security, all measures are means to counter a specific threat. You did not state your threat, so it will be difficult to know what you are trying to protect yourself against.
>
> You did however mention video games, and asked if it was possible to encrypt the game data with a machine-specific key, so that it can't simply be copied to a different system. I will base my answer off this specific threat model, but I am open to more suggestions.

---

## Why do you want to use encryption?

Encryption should protect the confidentiality of the data you encrypt. Only those who know the key to decrypt the data should be able to read the data. Encryption is not necessarily to protect the confidentiality of data in transmission, but also at rest.

On the surface, this sounds like what you want to do. You want to encrypt your data with said key, then decrypt it once the user wants to play your game.

## A whole lot of problems

Sadly, this idea will lead to many problems, and probably will not give you any protection at all.

### The gaming PC of Theseus Problem

Theseus was the mythical king and founder-hero of Athens. A little known fact about him was that he was also a passionate gamer, and loved building his own gaming PC. In fact, he was so passionate about it, that he always wanted to most powerful, up-to-date hardware.

First he upgraded his graphics card from a ψτω ΗΠ to a ψτω ΘΠ, then his CPU, hard drive, motherboard, case, PSU and more.

At some point his wife asked Theseus how many gaming PCs he has had so far, and he couldn't answer. Was it still the same gaming PC that he started with, even though it had no original parts anymore? At what point did it stop being his first PC?

While this may seem like a purely philosophical question at first, it does pose an interesting practical implication: What if your users modify their hardware somehow? What if a graphics card burns out and the user buys a new one? What if they upgrade their motherboard?

If your application behaves in a paranoid way, any *any* change to the hardware invalidates all their data, then people will quickly head for the hills and find a competitor. It doesn't even need to be a change in the hardware. If you read something like the BIOS as well, then any *update* to the system will invalidate it. Keep this in mind: Normal use of the computer could potentially invalidate the data.

### Kerckhoffs's Principle

There was once a dutchman with a fancy beard, going by the name of Auguste Kerckhoffs. He was really into cryptography, and he made some principles in regards to good crypto design.

While there are six rules, only the second rule is of importance to us:

> 2. *[The cryptosystem]* should not require secrecy, and it should not be a problem if it falls into enemy hands.

More simply put, all should depend on the secrecy of the key. If your enemy is the user, and the secret component is some property of the PC of the user, then the enemy has access to the key as well.

As a result, the end user can, either manually or with a tool that will play chiptune music while running, read out their keys, decrypt the files, copy them over to an unauthorized system, and then encrypt them with the keys of the new system. As a result, **your system fails completely**.

### More crypto is better!

Some may suggest to sign the encrypted data on your server before sending it to the client. The client may then be able to decrypt it, but cannot create a forged copy of the game to play on a different PC!

Well, they don't need to. Your data is already decrypted. All they have to do is use a custom executable, that does not attempt to decrypt the data, and the user can copy as much as they want.

## Is there no way for this to work?

Not really. DRM, which is all this scheme is in its current form, is a complicated game of cat-and-mouse. And for good reason, more and more developers choose to *remove* DRM from their games after a certain time past the release.

The goal of DRM is mostly to prevent piracy in the first week of the game's launch, when people make the decision whether to buy or to pirate the game. The downside is that the games run terrible, install rootkits on the PC or otherwise make life living hell for legitimate customers.

## But what about non-videogames? What about general things?

The flaws largely remain the same, and that is that users will find out which data is used as the key material, and then be able to manually decrypt their files.

Depending on how widespread your system is/will be, certain groups may release easy-to-use tools to dump those keys, or to decrypt them altogether.

Comment: Very satisfying as this discussion exposes clearly concrete flaws. many thanks.

Comment: @Abderrahimben In the future, please include a Threat Model in your question. Aka. "What are you trying to protect yourself from?" This way, answers can be more specific.

Comment: I acknowledge that I didn't point clearly what the threat model is because I didn't have a picture of any options. But I asked about flaws and opened the question about feasibility at first place; your response is very satisfying about both.

Comment: @Abderrahimben A threat model can be "Players can copy the game to a different PC. I want to stop that". It doesn't need to fully explain how it works.

Comment: _The downside is that the games run terrible, install rootkits on the PC or otherwise make life living hell for legitimate customers._ This has been true since the beginning of time! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenslok